# getting null pointer exception sending data to db using spring batch and csv file format

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

```
  package com.batch.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import com.batch.model.User;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuildFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> reader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<User> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("springbachdata.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(getlineMapper());
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        return reader;
    }

    private LineMapper<User> getlineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<User> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "Emp ID", "Name Prefix", "First Name", "Last Name" });
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 4 });
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor() {
        return new UserItemProcessor();

    }

    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<User>());
        writer.setSql(
                "insert into user(userId,namePrefix,firstName,lastName) values (:userId, :namePrefix, :firstName, :lastName)");
        writer.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        return writer;
    }
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("USER-IMPORT-JOB")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
                
    }
@Bean
    public Step step1() {
return this.stepBuildFactory.get("step1")
.<User, User>chunk(10)
.reader(reader())
.processor(processor())
.writer(writer())
.build();
    
    }
}
```

> > 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.batch.item.database.ItemPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(Object,
> > java.sql.PreparedStatement)" because
> > "this.this$0.itemPreparedStatementSetter" is null     at
> > org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:190)
> > ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]    at
> > org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:186)
> > ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]    at
> > org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
> > ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]    at
> > org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:691)
> > ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]    at
> > org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:186)
> > ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]    at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
> > ~[spring-tx-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
> > ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]    at
> > org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
> > ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]    at
> > org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
> > ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]    at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:149)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
> > ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]    at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> > Method) ~[na:na]  at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
> > ~[na:na]  at
> > java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> > ~[na:na]  at
> > java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
> > at
> > org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
> > ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> > org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
> > ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> > org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> > ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> > org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
> > ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.3.jar:4.3.3]  at
> > org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> > ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> > org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> > ~[spring-aop-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]     at
> > jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy58.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]   at
> > org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199)
> > ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]  at
> > org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
> > ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]  at
> > org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
> > ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]  at
> > org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
> > ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]  at
> > org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
> > ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]  at
> > org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:782)
> > ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> > org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:772)
> > ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> > org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:345)
> > ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> > org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
> > ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> > org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
> > ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]    at
> > com.batch.CsvToMysqlApplication.main(CsvToMysqlApplication.java:10)
> > ~[classes/:na]
>
> [2m2021-08-28 10:24:36.741[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10388[0;39m
> [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m
> [36mo.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep        [0;39m [2m:[0;39m
> Step: [step1] executed in 72ms [2m2021-08-28 10:24:36.768[0;39m
> [32m INFO[0;39m [35m10388[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[
> main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher     [0;39m
> [2m:[0;39m Job: [FlowJob: [name=USER-IMPORT-JOB]] completed with the
> following parameters: [{run.id=4}] and the following status: [FAILED]
> in 134ms '
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: You didn't include the one specific class where the NPE is, but most likely the problem is that it's not a Spring bean. Avoid `@Autowired` fields; generally replace them with constructors or (in the case of `@Bean` methods) parameters.

Comment: thankx for your reply but i am not getting your answer properly can u explain it thanks a lot

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Please make LineMapper method as public and add @Bean annotation. Also add @Bean annotation above the JdbcBatchItemWriter method.

```
@Bean
public LineMapper<User> getlineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<User> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "Emp ID", "Name Prefix", "First Name", "Last Name" });
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 4 });
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer() {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<User>());
        writer.setSql(
                "insert into user(userId,namePrefix,firstName,lastName) values (:userId, :namePrefix, :firstName, :lastName)");
        writer.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        return writer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity use a separate temp user class as **UserInput** for reading the data and one entity class which represent in table e.i **User* entity

**UserInput**

```
public class UserInput {

    private String userId;
    private String namePrefix;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String userId;
    private String namePrefix;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;        

}
```

**UserDataProcessor**

```
public class UserDataProcessor implements ItemProcessor<UserInput, User> {

    @Override
    public User process(UserInput userInput) throws Exception {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUserId(userInput.getUserId());
        user.setNamePrefix(userInput.getNamePrefix());
        user.setFirstName(userInput.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userInput.getLastName());
        System.out.println(user);
        return user;
    }

}
```

**BatchConfig**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class BatchConfig {
    
        private final String[] FIELD_NAMES = new String[] { "userId", "namePrefix", "firstName", "lastName" };
    
        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;
        @Autowired
        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
        @Bean
        public FlatFileItemReader<UserInput> reader() {
            return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<UserInput>().name("personItemReader")
                    .resource(new ClassPathResource("user-data.csv")).delimited().names(FIELD_NAMES)
                    .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<UserInput>() {
                        {
                            setTargetType(UserInput.class);
                        }
                    }).build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public UserDataProcessor processor() {
            return new UserDataProcessor();
    
        }
        @Bean
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer() {
            return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<User>()
                    .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                    .sql("INSERT INTO user (userId,namePrefix,firstName,lastName) "
                            + "VALUES (:userId,:namePrefix,:firstName,:lastName)")
                    .dataSource(dataSource).build();
    
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(step1)
                    .end().build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer) {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<UserInput, User>chunk(10).reader(reader()).processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer).build();
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

call writer.afterPropertiesSet() for your writer.

Reference [https://salzotech.blogspot.com/2017/02/nullpointerexception-in.html]